# Adding onClick to button in dialog layout, that doesn't have class

Tags: android, button, dialog, listener

I have dialog layout xml file which stores button, and I have set `android:onClick="doSomething"`, but I dont have any class files attached to that dialog. So practically dialog_layout.xml is the only file that I have in my project. I am able to show it and able to interact with it, but I can't make onClick listener for the button in dialog. 
I tried making the Activity that launches my dialog an owner of that dialog and then in that Activity create public void doSomething(View view) but it still doesnt seem to work. I get this error:

```
08-03 23:39:23.085: E/AndroidRuntime(6757): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method doSomething(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button2'
```

any idea what am I doing wrong?

EDIT
here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do something.
        } 
    });




    Preference keyP = (Preference) findPreference("keyP");
    keyP.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {



            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SettingsActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.draws_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Title");
            dialog.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: No wonder it's not working. Add code where you create and show dialog, we will add missing parts then. You are apparently inflating dialog layout. There is a place to add button click listener.

Comment: i edited my question, now includes code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good except you need to add button from code as it is recommended. After you loaded dialog layout the following code needs to be added. Note that you need to get rid of buttons in your xml layout, in this case android will create buttons with current theme style.

```
dialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Do something", 
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO do something here
    }
});
return dialog;
```

If you want your button has a specific design or features then you can use following:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.draws_dialog);
Button myDialogButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
myDialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Click listeners can be moved out of dialog generation body.

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener myButtonClickListener = new
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO: do something here with click
});
```

And dialog generation body will look like this:

```
dialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Do something", myButtonClickListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can have an Activity with a dialog theme such as you can have in your manifest

```
<activity android:name="MyDialog" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

Then that Activity will look exactly as a Dialog

Answer (score 0):

In the `Dialog` class, there is a method called [`findViewById(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#findViewById%28int%29). So, if you gave your button an id, you should get its instance with this method. Then you can add an OnClickListener to the Button using the method [`setOnClickListener (View.OnClickListener l)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29).

Comment: gives me error: 08-04 00:22:22.775: E/AndroidRuntime(10949): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: That's not the right error. There should be one below the RuntimeException. You should post your code in your question, as Maxim said.